# Can I append items to a list that I am looping through in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python: Adding element to list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752618/python-adding-element-to-list-while-iterating)

This doesn't seem to work, but I am not sure why:

```
for n in poss:
         poss.append(n+6)
```

Is there some rule that says I can't append items to a list that I am currently looping through?

Comment: Need to use a copy. Use a slice: `poss[::]` a tuple: `tuple(poss)` or a duplicate list: `list(poss)` which is the same as the slice form...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Appending to the list while iterating through it will enter an infinite loop, since you are adding more elements to the loop in each iteration.

You should iterate on a copy of the list instead. For example, try the following:

```
for n in tuple(poss):
    poss.append(n+6)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code actually works, but never ends because poss is continously growing.
Try:

```
poss = [1,2]

for n in poss:
    poss.append(n+6)
    if n > 10:
        print poss
        break
```

produces:

```
[1, 2, 7, 8, 13, 14, 19]
```