# Trying to remove the list if special character in string not working for all

Tags: python

```
['#', 'vcrisan', '#sses', '#crusu', 'ALL', '#rpavlicek', 'oracle', '#vcrisan', 'dwilks,skumar', 'sjoshi,skekes', 'skekes', 'sdammalapati', 'sdammalapati']
```

> I am trying to remove string with # in the list and if the string is
>   like 'dwilks,skumar' will split it again and add to the string again
>   removing the  old one.

The condition I am using is working but for single time only

```
            for name in userslist:
                if '#' in name:
                    userslist.remove(name)
                if ',' in name:
                    newwlist=name.split(',')
                    userslist.remove(name)
                    for splittedname in newwlist:
                        userslist.append(splittedname)

            print (userslist)
```

**Result:**

['vcrisan', '#crusu', 'ALL', 'oracle', 'dwilks,skumar', 'skekes', 'sdammalapati', 'sdammalapati', 'sjoshi', 'skekes']

**It's working for the first two # hash and not for the third one similarly for the comma case it working for the second value sjoshi,skekes only**

**NOTE:**
Please donot recommend **re** module

Comment: Don't remove from a list you iterate on (hundreds of duplicates).

Comment: example please do you mean to  use iter() instead

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752618/python-adding-element-to-list-while-iterating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may help you,

```
 userslist = ['#', 'vcrisan', '#sses', '#crusu', 'ALL', '#rpavlicek', 'oracle', '#vcrisan', 'dwilks,skumar', 'sjoshi,skekes', 'skekes', 'sdammalapati', 'sdammalapati']

    pUserList = []
    for name in userslist:
       if not name.startswith('#'):  
          pUserList.extend(name.split(',')) 

    print (pUserList)
```

Comment: extend is used rather than my way of spliting and adding again. But where is it mentioned remove with # . So if its not found does the extend removes it

Comment: It will skip any entry starts with '#'. Split will return a list with two or more element in case of `,` and one  element if the entry has no `,`.

Comment: cool. Its checking for the one without # so others wont be taken and extending  use working great with the one with comma, Thanks

Comment: NOTE:so the extends works even though comma is not found and performs the insertion for found item

Comment: Yes, A list with single entry ([element])  also will be considered as a list. So extend will work.