# Append 0 after specific element in the same list by updating the length using python

Tags: python, list, append

I have a problem which is similar to this.

Here I am trying to append 0 after every 5 in the list.

The below code does not update the length of the list and the output I get is `[1,4,5,0,2,7,5,0,5]` while desired output is `[1,4,5,0,2,7,5,0,5,0]`

```
mylist1 = [1,4,5,2,7,5,5]

for i in range(len(mylist1)):
    if mylist1[i] == 5:
         mylist1.insert(i+1,0)
print(f'output: {mylist1}')
```

I have to update in the same list mylist1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: Adding element to list while iterating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752618/python-adding-element-to-list-while-iterating)

Comment: Do you want a new list or does this have to be done *in situ*?

Comment: Yes you answered my question. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
mylist1 = [1,4,5,2,7,5,5]

for i, value in enumerate(mylist1):
    if value == 5:
         mylist1.insert(i+1, 0)
print(f'output: {mylist1}')
```

Comment: As a general rule, you should not modify any iterable whilst you're enumerating it. In this particular case it works but if you were removing elements you'd find yourself in trouble

Answer (score 0):

Problem is when you insert an item into list, the list length changed. So your loop not iterate all items.

Try this:

```
mylist1 = [1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 5, 5]

list_index = 0
while list_index < len(mylist1):
    if mylist1[list_index] == 5:
        mylist1.insert(list_index + 1, 0)
        list_index = list_index + 1
    list_index += 1
print(f'output: {mylist1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

The `list.insert` method costs *O(n)* in time complexity, so calling it in a loop makes the overall time complexity *O(n ^ 2)*.

To do this in linear time complexity, you can instead create a new list by iterating over the input list and appending `0` when seeing a `5`.

```
output = []
for i in mylist1:
    output.append(i)
    if i == 5:
        output.append(0)
```

If you do want the original list changed, you can copy the new list to the original in-place:

```
mylist1[:] = output
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/ProperGrownDatum

Answer (score 0):

You can safely iterate over your list in reverse like this:

```
mylist1 = [1, 4, 5, 2, 7, 5, 5]

for i in range(len(mylist1)-1, -1, -1):
    if mylist1[i] == 5:
        mylist1.insert(i+1, 0)

print(f'output: {mylist1}')
```